# G Suite Developer Hub execution list?

Tags: google-apps-script

In the list of "My Executions" on the Developer Hub there is a project that keeps showing up named "Advanced Summary by Awesome Table" that I have just noticed.  Just one of them shows the script as running 166,847 times with 24,178 users.  The container is not owned by me (the owner is shown as "Support Account"), neither is the project. This is listed as an Add on. I have no idea why this is executing and I can not stop it.  Executions continued to run, a few every second.  The Project's OAuth scope concerns me.

Does anyone know what this might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you google "Advanced Summary by Awesome Table" it comes up as a Chrome Extension, available from the [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-summary-by-aweso/acjijfibfkinmiggeggndoeolggfahhl?hl=en). If you enter `chrome://extensions/` into your browser I expect you will see it.

If I look at my personal My Executions (removing the filtering so I see everything), I too am seeing records for Add-ons (i.e. my chrome extensions); see picture below. So I guess that this is fairly normal. Although I don't see 'container' or 'owner' information, or understand how to check the OAuth scope. So I'm not sure what you are referring to there; perhaps you could provide a screen-shot?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.  At one time I did add the Awesome Table add-on, but removed it more than 18 months ago.  Unlike the other add-ons that I see in the My Executions list, the Awesome Table on is clickable. Here's what I see when I do that:  [Advanced Summary by Awesome Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivxGo.png)

Here is project's OAuth:  [OAuth Scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHmlT.png)

And the container is this: [Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mSKf.png)

I don't own this form and I have no idea why this onOpen is is running so often by so many.  It really does concern me.